# How to preserve original author on cherry-pick smartgit

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, smartgit, cherry-pick

I'm using smartgit to manage an SVN repo. We have 2 branches, trunk, and release. We are cherry-picking commits from trunk to release as they are ready. How do I set up smartgit to retain the author of the original commit on the cherry pick? Thank you in advance!

Comment: While Git is able to keep author names independent, SVN is not. As soon as you check in Git commits into Subversion, the original author data no longer matters and the Subversion server decides about the content. And the author is taken from the user checking in the changes.

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. I thought there might be some setting somewhere I was missing. We have been manually changing the authors through SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can make SmartGit use the options `--add-author-from` and `--use-log-author` on its internal `git svn dcommit` ([options illustrated  in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5941222/6309)), that would not be supported.

And even then, that would [only add information in the revision message](https://github.com/Bioconductor/BiocGithubHelp/wiki/Preserve-git-committer-in-dcommit), without changing the actual author.
(I have also seen also [adding an SVN property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416722/6309))